# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present when using sharethis API with Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to get the social count from sharethis through their API: https://www.sharethis.com/social-share-count-api/

However when I get the following error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rest.sharethis.com/v1/count/urlinfo?url=https://someurl.com No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

I've seen solutions using php but is it possible to pull the share count through liquid/shopify?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `sharethis.com` is not set up to allow you to query it directly from the browser like this, is it has not enabled cross origin resource sharing. If you don't own sharethis, you can't change that.

What you can do is write a backend endpoint in your own application that proxies sharethis though.

[This MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) explains why the browser explicitly checks that this is allowed by the other domain.